# Change Key of HttpContext.Request.Query item in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to work around a issue with a 3rd party filter.  My current plan is to put a filter in front of that filter to "fix" the query string so it does not error out.

I made an ActionFilterAttribute and added it into the filter list.  It is running fine.  I am adding my logic in the `OnActionExecuting` method.

The first item of `context.HttpContext.Request.Query` has a Key that is a json structure.  I need to change that Key to be `{}`.

Problem is that both `context.HttpContext.Request.Query` and `context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString` are read-only.

**How can I alter the `context.HttpContext.Request.Query` or the `context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString`?**

*EDIT - The Underlying Problem:*
BreezeJS did a minimal level upgrade to support .NET Core.  In this upgrade, part of the code expects that every call that has any parameters to return an IQueryable ([QueryFns.cs Line 32](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/AspNetCore/Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore/QueryFns.cs)).  From reading the code it seems like this is an error (the calling function ([the actual filter](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/AspNetCore/Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore/QueryFilter.cs)) seems to just expect null to be returned not an Exception.)

Either way, this makes moving to .NET Core very hard.

I considered my other options and if this fails, I will continue to pursue them:

1. *Submit a pull request to fix the issue*: The project has not accepted any pull requests in over a year and a half.  So it seems unlikely my request will be taken.
2. *Fork my own branch:* I would rather not have to create and maintain a separate version with my own build and publishing pipeline.
3. *Find a way to make the Breeze filter ignore the call when the result is not an IQueryable*: I am currently looking into this one. (This question.)
4. *Find a way to send my call from the client differently so that breeze ignores calls that do not return IQueryable*: The return type of the call is owned by the service.  And this is an issue with the service.  I would rather not have to have tight coupling between the service and the client such that the client is crafting workarounds for service filter issues.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You're having problem X, and you've decided on solution Y. However, you don't know how to do Y, either. Instead of asking about X, you're asking about Y, and Y isn't even a valid solution. You cannot change the query string. Period. It's part of the URI, which is fundamentally the core of the request. The only thing you could possibly do is redirect to the URI with the query string modified, but that would require the client to issue a new request and assumes that this 3rd party filter wouldn't just mess that up too. Give more detail about the actual issue.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I added the detail of the original problem